# Is there a proper name for the 3 asterisks that are used to suggest temporal discontinuity?

Tags: punctuation, writing, books, symbols

For example, when some long prose passage ends, this appears:

* *  *

Then some new prose passage begins.  The three asterisks dividing the two prose sections are understood to divide the two sections into non-continuous temporal spaces.

I am interested in knowing if there is a *specific name* to describe *symbolic or graphical* markings that are meant to suggest *temporal discontinuity*.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about three-asterisk breaks, or the more general class of breaks that also includes short lines, single asterisks, and other graphic symbols?

Comment: @Monica: edited question to clarify object of my inquiry

Comment: +1 This is something I have wondered somewhere in the back of my mind.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26385/what-do-you-call-those-divisions-of-a-book-bigger-than-a-paragraph-but-smaller-th/26389

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems that these are called ["section breaks"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_break) (sometimes ["scene breaks"](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090623052529AABwWFv)):

> Sections are visually separated from each other with a section break, typically consisting of extra space between the sections. They are a concern in the process of typography and pagination, where it may be desirable to have a page break follow a section break for the sake of aesthetics or readability.
>   In fiction, sections often represent scenes, and accordingly the space separating them is sometimes also called a scene break.

[image]

The bottom left of the image shows a section break. A section break doesn't necessarily need to be only three asterisks, although that is the most common. In this [blog,](http://henrymelton.blogspot.com/2009/01/caught-between-paper-and-bits-scene.html) it shows that the section breaks could be hash signs as well.

Alternatively, it could be an ["asterism" :](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterism_(typography))

> In typography, an asterism, from the Greek astēr ('star'),[1](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090623052529AABwWFv) is a rarely used, and "nearly obsolete",[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PVeY.jpg) symbol consisting of three asterisks placed in a triangle (⁂). It is used to, "indicate minor breaks in text,

Later on the text from the link, it seems that an asterism is usually written like " * * *" :

> Often, this symbol is replaced with three, sometimes more, consecutive asterisks or dots.

Comment: Hah, it's really funny that you linked to a wikipedia page including LaTeX code, b/c my reason for asking this question in the first place was that I was in the middle of writing a business letter, and I wanted to find the LaTeX code for asterism or whatever it turns out to be called.

Comment: +1 @Thursagen I'm leaning toward **Scene Break**.  Thanks for the blog link, very interesting stuff.  I'll leave this up for a bit to see if anything else pops up.

Comment: I've also seen scene breaks marked by more complicated typographical elements; the name for these might be [fleurons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleuron_%28typography%29) (although it seems they're more often just called "ornaments.")

Comment: @Peter Shor yes, by all means, I have seen things other than asterisks as well.  Good point.

Comment: This answer is wrong. It even misquotes the Wikipedia article. The correct quote is: "Often, this symbol is replaced with three consecutive asterisks (called a *dinkus*) ..." The correct answer is the one by Cedric Eveleigh: three asterisks in a row are called a "dinkus".

Comment: This might be one use of *asterism*, and correct, but I think among people who know the word at all, most will think of the most prominent, visible, and recognizable portion of a constellation, ie. Orion's belt.

Answer (score 9):

I have heard that construct (a line of asterisks meant to suggest a temporal or logical disconnect) described as a "zareba," back in my days as a typesetter, but I am unable to find a reference for that usage, even in the venerable OED -- it may have been local to SF Bay typesetters, or just used by typesetters in general.

Comment: +1 for the interesting answer. According to the OED, a _zareba_ (or _zariba_) can refer either to "a pen or enclosure for cattle" or (in the Soudan region) to "a fence or inclosure usually constructed of thorn bushes for defence against the attacks of enemies or wild beasts." A company named Zareba Systems, in business since the 1940s, claims to be the largest maker of electric fence systems in North America. So it may be that a typesetter at some point equated the line of asterisks under discussion here with the thorny fence line of a zareba.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have the reputation to comment on @Alexa's post connecting Wodehouse and "zareba", but I tracked down an example of Wodehouse's usage in this context. In his story "Something to Worry About", he writes (emphasis mine):

> The dramatist brings down the curtain on such speeches. **The novelist blocks his reader's path with a zareba of stars.** But in life there are no curtains, no stars, nothing final and definite—only ragged pauses and discomfort. There was such a pause now.

(Available on [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/6768/6768-h/6768-h.htm).)

It looks like Wodehouse liked to use "zareba" in a variety of contexts describing metaphorical enclosures or fortifications, not just referring to a section break, e.g., ["Vladimir Brusiloff had permitted his face to become almost entirely concealed behind a dense zareba of hair"](https://honoriaplum.wordpress.com/2015/01/25/wodehouse-and-the-melancholy-beard/), ["Mr. Benham’s eyes opened behind their zareba of glass."](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/3756/3756-h/3756-h.htm). Based on this, certainly seems plausible Wodehouse was the origin of the term in a typesetting context!

Answer (score 5):

According to wikipedia, *** used as a section break is called a *dinkus*.

Source:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/***

Comment: The [Asterism page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterism_(typography)) gives the source for that label as a book: Lundmark, Torbjorn Quirky Qwerty: A Biography of the Keyboard (2002)

Answer (score 4):

> In typography, an asterism, from the Greek astēr ('star'),1 is a
>   rarely used, and "nearly obsolete",2 symbol consisting of three
>   asterisks placed in a triangle (⁂). It is used to, "indicate minor
>   breaks in text.

An even more ancient name is MUL -- from the cuneiform (oldest writing). In Babylonian language 'istari' meant god or goddess, though it could also mean star, heaven or sun/planet. The asterisk and the use of three as a triangle are all original to that cuneiform writing system as a pre-determinative sign indicating stars and the names of constellations. The single 'asterisk' often denoted the proper names of gods and goddesses of Mesopotamian tradition. ("Secrets of Sumerian Language" -Joshua Free)

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking all over for the answer to this. Although this usually refers to a decorative line, the generic term for a graphic that splits up a page is called an ornamental rule.  Most people call the space between a scene break. Some of the other people here seem to have the specific name for * * *
I hope you found what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The term "zareba" is familiar to me as a description of the line of three asterisks used in modern print to signify a break of some kind.  I think I learned the word in the writing of P. G. Wodehouse.  Wodehouse (1881-1975) was a British comic writer.  He wrote in several media, including as a magazine columnist, and I think he referred to the line of asterisks with ironic consciousness within a story or two.

Comment: Winnie Kelly's answer above also mentions _zareba_. If you can remember where in Wodehouse you saw his mention of the term, please add it to your answer!